# Echo not displaying the whole string

Tags: php

I have this code.

```
<?php echo "<a href=pvendors.php?post=".$par.">".$row['pname']."</a>";?></h4>
```

When I click on the link,Its only posting the first word of the string,the rest are ignored

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: What is `$par`? You should put quotes around your attributes, that is probably the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Missing the quotes for `href` attribute -

```
echo "<a href='pvendors.php?post=".$par."'>".$row['pname']."</a>";
```